# How to access other services inside a Symfony FormType?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I try to access a service from a FormType extended by AbstractType. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just inject services you want through constructor to the form type.

```
class FooType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $barService;

    public function __construct(BarService $barService)
    {
        $this->barService = $barService;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->barService->doSomething();
        // (...)
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll also need to add the new argument to the FormType declaration in services file, e.g. in services.yml

Comment: in order to make this answer fully working, your form type should be [defined as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service)

Answer (score 5):

As a complete answer based on previous answers/comments:

In order to access to a service from your Form Type, you have to:

1) [Define your Form Type as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service) and inject the needed service into it:

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    app.my.form.type:
        class: AppBundle\Form\MyFormType # this is your form type class
        arguments:
            - '@my.service' # this is the ID of the service you want to inject
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

2) Now in your form type class, inject it into the constructor:

```
// src/AppBundle/Form/MyFormType.php
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $myService;

    public function __construct(MyServiceClass $myService)
    {
        $this->myService = $myService;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->myService->someMethod();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at [this page in the sympfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service) for a description of how to declare your form type as a service. That page has a lot of good documentation and example.

Cyprian is on the right track, but the linked page takes it a step further by creating your form type as a service and having the DI container inject the service automatically.